# Facing XSS issue when javasrcript code is added in browser url

Tags: javascript, php, xss

The site is in PHP, on my site I have a url which is something like this::

```
http://localhost/test.php
```

The above url works really fine but when it is changed to something like below then it does not work properly:

```
http://localhost/test.php/#' onmouseover=prompt(962488) //
```

The css disappears and almost everything goes awry.
What should I do so that above malicious code does not create any problem ?

Comment: My guess is you aren't referencing your assets from the website root, and it's trying to serve your css from `http://localhost/test.php/#' onmouseover=prompt(962488) //style.css`.

Comment: @BenFortune Its from website root

Comment: Are your assets prepended with a `/`?

Comment: @BenFortune No, its simply "style.css" and not "/style.css"